Trying to dockerize a Maven project
I'm trying to dockerize the Apache Commons Daemons project. The directory is this:
project directory
I have followed this guide: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-do-you-dockerize-a-maven-project and I don't have any problem until the mvn install.
Then when I try to do the docker build i get the following error:
------
 > [2/2] ADD target/simple-docker.jar simple-docker.jar:
------
Dockerfile:21
--------------------
  19 |     
  20 |     FROM openjdk:8
  21 | >>> ADD target/simple-docker.jar simple-docker.jar
  22 |     ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","simple-docker.jar"]
  23 |     EXPOSE 8080
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 98866f48-ea55-426c-80eb-d2380731e691::i1dew1l2luwxdy8xrwia5eytv: "/target/simple-docker.jar": not found

This is the Dockerfile:
 # or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 # distributed with this work for additional information
 # regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 # "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 # with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 #
 #   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 #
 # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 # software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 # "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 # KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 # specific language governing permissions and limitations
 # under the License.
 #

FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/simple-docker.jar simple-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","simple-docker.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080

This is the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
   this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
   The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
   (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
   the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   limitations under the License.
-->
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-parent</artifactId>
    <version>77</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>commons-daemon</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-daemon</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Apache Commons Daemon</name>
  <!-- Daemon started in Commons in 2002 with an import of code from Tomcat,
       which is why the NOTICE file has an earlier date than the inceptionYear -->
  <inceptionYear>2002</inceptionYear>
  <description>
    Apache Commons Daemon software is a set of utilities and Java support
    classes for running Java applications as server processes. These are
    commonly known as 'daemon' processes in Unix terminology (hence the
    name). On Windows they are called 'services'.
  </description>
  <url>https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/</url>

  <issueManagement>
    <system>jira</system>
    <url>https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DAEMON</url>
  </issueManagement>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/commons-daemon.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf/commons-daemon.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://gitbox.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-daemon.git</url>
  </scm>

  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Jean-Frederic Clere</name>
      <id>jfclere</id>
      <email>jfclere at apache.org</email>
    </developer>

    <developer>
      <name>Remy Maucherat</name>
      <id>remm</id>
      <email>remm at apache.org</email>
    </developer>

    <developer>
      <name>Yoav Shapira</name>
      <id>yoavs</id>
      <email>yoavs at apache.org</email>
    </developer>

    <developer>
      <name>Bill Barker</name>
      <id>billbarker</id>
      <email>billbarker at apache.org</email>
    </developer>
    <developer>
      <name>Mladen Turk</name>
      <id>mturk</id>
      <email>mturk at apache.org</email>
    </developer>

    <developer>
      <name>Pier Fumagalli</name>
      <id>pier</id>
      <email>pier at apache.org</email>
    </developer>

    <developer>
      <id>ggregory</id>
      <name>Gary Gregory</name>
      <email>ggregory at apache.org</email>
      <url>https://www.garygregory.com</url>
      <organization>The Apache Software Foundation</organization>
      <organizationUrl>https://www.apache.org/</organizationUrl>      
      <roles>
        <role>PMC Member</role>
      </roles>
      <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
      <properties>
        <picUrl>https://people.apache.org/~ggregory/img/garydgregory80.png</picUrl>
      </properties>
    </developer>

  </developers>

  <contributors>
    <contributor>
      <name>Nick Griffiths</name>
      <email>nicobrevin@gmail.com</email>
    </contributor>
  </contributors>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <!-- Apache Commons Daemon is used by Apache Tomcat. The oldest currently
         supported Tomcat version is Tomcat 9 which has a minimum Java version
         of Java 8. It is therefore advisable to check with the Apache Tomcat
         community before increasing these values. -->
    <animal-sniffer.signature>java18</animal-sniffer.signature>
    <commons.daemon.javaversion>1.8</commons.daemon.javaversion>
    <maven.compiler.source>${commons.daemon.javaversion}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${commons.daemon.javaversion}</maven.compiler.target>
    <commons.componentid>daemon</commons.componentid>
    <commons.module.name>org.apache.commons.daemon</commons.module.name>
    <commons.release.version>1.4.1</commons.release.version>
    <commons.rc.version>RC1</commons.rc.version>
    <commons.bc.version>1.4.0</commons.bc.version>
    <commons.jira.id>DAEMON</commons.jira.id>
    <commons.jira.pid>12310468</commons.jira.pid>
    <project.build.outputTimestamp>2024-01-01T00:00:00Z</project.build.outputTimestamp>
    <commons.jacoco.haltOnFailure>true</commons.jacoco.haltOnFailure>
    <!-- JaCoCo: Don't make code coverage worse than: -->
    <commons.jacoco.haltOnFailure>true</commons.jacoco.haltOnFailure>
    <commons.jacoco.classRatio>0.01</commons.jacoco.classRatio> <!-- abbassato a 0.01 da 0.12 -->
    <commons.jacoco.instructionRatio>0.00</commons.jacoco.instructionRatio>
    <commons.jacoco.methodRatio>0.01</commons.jacoco.methodRatio>
    <commons.jacoco.branchRatio>0.00</commons.jacoco.branchRatio>
    <commons.jacoco.lineRatio>0.00</commons.jacoco.lineRatio>
    <commons.jacoco.complexityRatio>0.00</commons.jacoco.complexityRatio>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <!-- Customise the default ASF Commons release profile -->
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <build>
        <finalName>simple-docker</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <!--
            Disable the default detach-distributions goal.
            Project specific configuration is provided below.
          -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <!-- Spelling error is deliberate to match parent pom -->
                <id>detatch-distributions</id>
                <phase>none</phase>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>clean verify apache-rat:check japicmp:cmp pmd:check pmd:cpd-check javadoc:javadoc</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.rat</groupId>
          <artifactId>apache-rat-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <!-- Free Software (see header) -->
              <exclude>src/native/unix/configure</exclude>
              <!-- GPL with applicable exception that allows ALv2 -->
              <exclude>src/native/unix/support/config.guess</exclude>
              <exclude>src/native/unix/support/config.sub</exclude>
              <!-- Files created by Configure -->
              <!-- Excluded from Git but may be present locally -->
              <exclude>src/native/unix/config.nice</exclude>
              <exclude>src/native/unix/config.status</exclude>
              <exclude>src/native/unix/config.log</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
          <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/native-src.xml</descriptor>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/src.xml</descriptor>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/win.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
          <tarLongFileMode>gnu</tarLongFileMode>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
              <mainClass>org.apache.commons.daemon.Docker.example</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Force detach-distributions to execute *after* Nexus deploy -->
      <!-- we want these distributions deployed to both Nexus and dist.a.o -->
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>detach-distributions</id>
            <phase>deploy</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>detach-distributions</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

There are some extra infos:

Class path
One and only warning in mvn install:
[WARNING] File commons-daemon-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar is already modular
example class code:

/*
 *  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 *  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 *  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 *  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 *  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 *  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */

package org.apache.commons.daemon.Docker;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class example
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {

        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
        server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();

    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "<h1> Hello World!!!! I just Dockerized a Maven Project </h1>";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }
}

If any other infos are needed I'll provide them as soon as possible.
Thank you

Did you do a mvn package -Prelease first? The -Prelease part is important because that triggers the profile that sets the file name to simple-docker.jar. Without it you get the default file name.

You're welcome.

mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The solution of Rob worked, so I haven't tried this
